# Triggers not firing in MySQL

Tags: mysql, triggers

I’m trying to set a Trigger in mysql database (5.7.17-log) to validate data during insert/update. However, I cannot get the triggers to fire (complete sql script attached).

Here is complete script:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `CUSTOMER_SERVICE`;
USE `CUSTOMER_SERVICE`;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CustomerRecord` (
  `ID` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `AGENT_ID` INTEGER DEFAULT 1,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
);

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `AgentIdCheck`(IN AGENT_ID INTEGER)
BEGIN
    IF ((AGENT_ID < 0) || (AGENT_ID >= 1000)) THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'AgentIdDCheck constraint failed';
    END IF;

END $$
DELIMITER ;

-- before insert
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `AgentIdCheck_Before_Insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `CustomerRecord`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    CALL AgentIdCheck(new.AGENT_ID);
END$$
DELIMITER ;

-- before update
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `AgentIdCheck_Before_Update` BEFORE UPDATE ON `CustomerRecord`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    CALL AgentIdCheck(new.AGENT_ID);
END $$
DELIMITER ;

INSERT INTO CustomerRecord (ID, AGENT_ID) VALUES ("Customer1", 5000);
```

I have tried `END $$`, `END$$`, `END;$$` etc, based on my search of existing questions. Please suggest.

Comment: Does not reproduce. Click on Run button on this link: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qrpBBujZZY3tT2i58JR8PQ/0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The triggers do fire but your procedure logic is incorrect - should be OR not and/&&